# Google Maps Javascript marker not displaying

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the following JavaScript to display a map with marker @ bottom left of https://brand.insightdesign.com.au:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    var grayStyles = [
    {
        featureType: "all",
        stylers: [
        { saturation: -90 },
        { lightness: 50 }
        ]
    },
    ];
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-31.947414, 115.835933),
    zoom: 15,
    styles: grayStyles,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var myLatLng = {lat: -31.947414, lng: 115.835933};

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Insight Branding'
    });                   
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: block; height: 180px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

The marker does not display.

There are no console errors about the map.

Help appreciated.

Steve

Comment: Something worth noting here. DO NOT show your company's API key.

Comment: your code seems to run fine. See http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/0hegLpku/

Maybe start with checking that your code was actually been deployed in that production site.

Comment: @SamuelToh It was Wordpress caching plugin which was caching the old code. Should we delete this question?

Comment: I think we'll leave it. Maybe I'll just do a quick write up on what the solution is to give this a closure. Hopefully it will be helpful to someone in future to remind them of the caching bit when similar situation occurs again.

Comment: P.S I don't understand why was this question down voted? I find it legit, we all make this kind of mistake once inawhile?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** Why isn't my marker showing?

**A:** As discussed in the comments section. The code is a valid one, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/0hegLpku.

```
_
```

The problem turns out to be a caching plugin which OP have used in for his production site. It was causing his production site to be still on the old code. Therefore no changes was observed.